# Microsoft Word - How to Replace Double Paragraph Breaks with a Wildcard Search?

Tags: microsoft-word, find

How can I Find or Replace a double paragraph break (aka empty paragraph) in MS Word?

Using
`Find: ^p^p`
will not work because the search function only returns matches found in one paragraph. (This is similar to how grep in Linux only returns matches found in one line)

Answer (score 1):

1. Find and Replace.
2. Check the Search Option box "Use Wildcards."
3. Instead of ^p^p use the ANSI code for paragraph mark:
   `^013{2,}`

A curly bracket is a quantifier so {2,4} matches 2 to 4 breaks and {2,} just means 2 or more.

Thanks to
https://intelligentediting.com/blog/replacing-double-paragraph-breaks-with-a-wildcard-search/
and more details are available there.